# Showing history of a filename (that is deleted and added throughout history)

Tags: svn

I have a situation where a filename has been deleted and added several times in the history and want to see the history of that.

However if I try to use `svn log <filename>` it only shows the history from the last time the filename was added. I realize that subversion won't regard earlier incarnations of the filename to be the same file and it looks like subversion is trying to show the history of the file itself and not the name.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run `svn log <REPO-URL> --verbose --search <FILENAME>` or `svn log <REPO-URL> --verbose --search <PATH-TO-FILE>` in this case.

BTW, instead of re-importing the deleted file, you can run `svn copy` command. [Resurrecting deleted items with `svn copy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect) keeps the history link.

Comment: This seem to depend on svn 1.8 which (IIUC) is not considered released yet. I think you should have been clearer on this. Preferably the answer should be applicable to a released version of subversion. Alas I'm using v1.6.17, but I guess I can't blame anyone but me or my employer for that...

Comment: @skyking current svn version is 1.9 and 1.10 is in alpha. Svn 1.6 is very outdated. Btw, --search is a client side feature. You can get latest command line tools at https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/ and try it yourself.

Comment: I looked for the documentation for `--search` and the subversion book seems a bit behind (it's still at 1.7 with 1.8 being "nightly builds").

Comment: @skyking that's partially my fault. SVNBook is an open source project and I've been updating its 1.8 version some time ago. IMO its mostly ready to be considered as final 1.8, but definitely lacks proofreading and further review.